# ModelForm save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'

Tags: python, django

i try to make custom user in `django` but have a problem with, please help.

The probem is when I add or change the user from the admin and save it, i am not understand where the problem is but i feel in `form.py`, please help me to fix this.

```
models.py


class ObUser(AbstractUser):
    SEX = (
        ('M', 'MALE'),
        ('F', 'FEMALE'),
    )
    username    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    email       = models.EmailField(max_length=30, unique=True, blank=False, null=False)
    first_name  = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank= False, null=False)
    last_name   = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank= False, null=False)
    password    = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    born_date   = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    address     = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    phone       = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    sim_id      = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    quotes      = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    sex         = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=SEX)
    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    last_login  = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    last_update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False, blank=True, null=True)
    date_joined = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    objects     = ObUserManager
```

and then i make the ModelForm :

```
form.py

class ObUserCreate(forms.ModelForm):
    password1 = forms.CharField(label='password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='konfirmasi password', widget=forms.PasswordInput)


    class Meta:
        model       = ObUser
        fields      = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'password')


    def clean_password2(self):
        password1=self.cleaned_data.get('password1')
        password2=self.cleaned_data.get('password2')
        if password1 and password2 and password1 != password2:
            raise forms.ValidationError('password tidak sama')
        return password2

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.clean_password2()
        user = super().save(commit=False)
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password2'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user

class ObUserChange(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model       = ObUser
        exclude     = ['last_login', 'last_update', 'date_joined', 'is_verified']

    def save(self):
        user = super().save()
        if first_name and last_name and born_date and address and phone and sim_id and quotes and sex:
            user.is_verified=True
            user.save()
        user.save()
        return user
```

and admin like this

```
class UserAdm(UserAdmin):
    form            = ObUserChange
    add_form        = ObUserCreate
    list_display    = ('username', 'email', 'is_active', 'is_verified')
    fieldsets       = (None, {'fields': ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'born_date', 'address', 'phone', 'sim_id', 'sex')}),
    add_fieldsets   = (None, {'fields': ('username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')}),  
    search_fields   = ('username',)
    ordering        = ('email',)
admin.site.register(ObUser, UserAdm)
```

but i have error like :

> Request Method:    POST
>   Request URL:    http://localhost/admin/obusers/obuser/add/
>   Django Version: 2.2.2
>   Exception Type: TypeError
>   Exception Value:
>   save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'
>   Exception Location: D:\project\django\tutorials\env\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py in save_form, line 1082
>   Python Executable:  D:\project\django\tutorials\env\Scripts\python.exe
>   Python Version: 3.7.3
>   Python Path:
>   ['D:\project\django\tutorials\otobrothers',
>    'C:\Users\masdika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python37.zip',
>    'C:\Users\masdika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\DLLs',
>    'C:\Users\masdika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib',
>    'C:\Users\masdika\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37',
>    'D:\project\django\tutorials\env',
>    'D:\project\django\tutorials\env\lib\site-packages']
>   Server time:    Sun, 30 Jun 2019 06:26:55 +0000

thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just try adding `*args, **kwargs` in save() method

```
def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
            use  = self.clean_password2()
            user = super().save(commit=False)
            if use:
                user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password2'])
                user.save()
            return user
```

Comment: it still make error save() got an unexpected keyword argument 'commit'

Comment: @blanksix updated my answer.Try giving some other name instead of `save`  for password save

Comment: if we change method to save_password is not that will not work when form trying to save ?